# Editable table on JQuery and html?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to make a PivotTable for editing the data without refresh, but when double-clicking the line nothing happens, follows the JQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tblEditavel tbody tr td.editavel').dblclick(function(){
        if($('td > input').length > 0){
            return;
        }
        var conteudoOriginal = $(this).text();
        var novoElemento = $('<input/>', {type: 'text', value:conteudoOriginal});

        $(this).html(novoElemento.bind('blur keydown', function(e){
            var keyCode = e.which;
            var conteudoNovo = $(this).val();
            if(keyCode == 13 && conteudoNovo != '' && conteudoNovo != conteudoOriginal){
                var objeto = $(this);
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"alterar.php",
                    data: {
                        id:$(this).parents('tr').children().first().text(),
                        campo:$(this).parent().attr('title'),
                        valor:conteudoNovo
                    }
                    success:function(result){
                        objeto.parent().html(conteudoNovo);
                        $('body').append(result);
                    }
                })
            }
            else if( keyCode == 27 || e.type == 'blur') {
                $(this).parent().html(conteudoOriginal);
            }
        }));
        $(this).children().select();
    }    
})})
```

code of the simple table HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="atualiza.js"></script>
    <style>
        table{
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        table, td, th{
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 5px;

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="tblEditavel">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Valor</th>
                <th>Vencimento</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>74</td>
                <td title="Nome" class="editavel">Fatura 45 Jhovini</td>
                <td title="valor" class="editavel">2.350,00</td>
                <td title="vencimento" class="editavel">10/02/2017</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
```

Before the code worked, but after putting the ajax it does not work with double click, what did I do wrong?

Comment: "It doesn't work" doesn't really describe the problem.  When you debug this, where/how specifically does it fail?  Is there an error on the browser console?  When you step through the code in the browser's debugger, does it do what you expect?  Is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?  Where does it fail?

Comment: @David Actually double-clicking it does not edit the table, the input is not working, I do not know where I got the jquery code, how it does not edit, it does not process the ajax code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a `,` before `succes` in `AJAX` and you have an extra closing `}` after `$(this).children().select();`. See the working snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tblEditavel tbody tr td.editavel').dblclick(function() {
      if ($('td > input').length > 0) {
        return;
      }
      var conteudoOriginal = $(this).text();
      var novoElemento = $('<input/>', {
        type: 'text',
        value: conteudoOriginal
      });
      $(this).html(novoElemento.bind('blur keydown', function(e) {
        var keyCode = e.which;
        var conteudoNovo = $(this).val();
        if (keyCode == 13 && conteudoNovo != '' && conteudoNovo != conteudoOriginal) {
          var objeto = $(this);
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "alterar.php",
            data: {
              id: $(this).parents('tr').children().first().text(),
              campo: $(this).parent().attr('title'),
              valor: conteudoNovo
            }, //added this comma here
            success: function(result) {
              objeto.parent().html(conteudoNovo);
              $('body').append(result);
            }
          })
        } else if (keyCode == 27 || e.type == 'blur'){
          $(this).parent().html(conteudoOriginal);
          }
      }));
      $(this).children().select();
    
        //} removed the extra } from here.
    });

  })
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblEditavel">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Valor</th>
      <th>Vencimento</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>74</td>
      <td title="Nome" class="editavel">Fatura 45 Jhovini</td>
      <td title="valor" class="editavel">2.350,00</td>
      <td title="vencimento" class="editavel">10/02/2017</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Where was the mistake? I wasted a lot of time trying. thank you so much.

Comment: @WagnerFernandoMomesso, You're welcome. Happy to help. As I specified in my answer also, you missed a `,` between `data` and `success` from `AJAX` function and you had an extra closing `}` which I removed. I've also edited my answer with comments for every modification I did.